# Как сделать, чтобы ошибка всплывала сверху EdiText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Я вывожу ошибку при помощи `my_editText.setError()`, но она выводиться "под" `EdiText`, как сделать, чтобы ошибка всплывала сверху, от `EditText`?

Comment: Сделать свой кастомный EditText либо воспользоваться библиотекой или другим видом показа сообщений об ошибке(смотрите в сторону dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если my_editText это экземпляр класса EditText, то я бы предложил тебе создать собственный класс расширяющий EditText, переопределить в нем метод setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon),а в нем создавать   android.widget.PopupWindow  и вызывать его метод showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y). Как пример:

```
public MyEditText extends EditText{
Context context;
EditText linkOfMyself;
...
@Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
       android.widget.PopupWindow mErrorPopup = new android.widget.PopupWindow(context);
       mErrorPopup.showAtLocation(linkOfMyself,customGravity,X,Y)
    }

}
```

Собственно похожим образом создается сообщение по умолчиню, только там используется метод showAsDropDown();